# Proper way to create taxonomy queries

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, array

How to build taxonomy queries dyniamically?

I have this code for dynamically creating an array for color and price:

```
$color = $_POST['color'];
$price = $_POST['price'];

if (!empty($color)) {
    $query_color =  array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'color',
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        'terms' => $color
        );
} else {
    $query_color = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'color',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => ''
    );
}

if (!empty($price)) {
    $query_price =  array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'price',
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        'terms' => $color
        );
} else {
    $query_price = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'price',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => ''
    );
}
```

And I have this code for a query:

```
$args = array(
        's' => $search,
        'post_type' => array( 'post' ),
        'posts_per_page' => 99999,
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            $query_color,
            $query_price,
        )
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But, it's not working good. It always shows all posts ad not just the things from the $color and $price array. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting the `color` and `price` variables from the URL? If so, you need to use `$_GET` not `$_POST`, and you may want to escape or validate your value.

Also I suggest not defining them as variables, because if there is no value for either of those taxonomies, you don't need the tax queries (it'll speed up the query).

Do it like this

```
$args = array( .....,
    'tax_query' => array( 'relation' => 'OR' ),
    ... );

if( $_GET['color'] )
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'color',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => $color
    );
```

Comment: I am using a form and ajax, not url, so POST is ok. Btw. the color or price is there anyway, even if the array is empty. Btw. could you write your code a little more specific I don;t get what you are saying at all?

Comment: I was going to say, that's pretty specific, not sure how to be more specific without doing your work for you. lol